# What happens using a Dispatcher v/s Main Thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In the context of Android, What is the difference between a dispatcher vs main thread.

As per my understanding referring the documentation,

> It is backed by a shared pool of threads on JVM. By default, the
> maximal level of parallelism used by this dispatcher is equal to the
> number of CPU cores, but is at least two. Level of parallelism X
> guarantees that no more than X tasks can be executed in this
> dispatcher in parallel.

Will it spawn a new thread or there will be as per the log name `DefaultDispatcher-worker-1` a worker that will communicate with the pool of threads other than the main to handle a block of co-routine or worker itself is a Co-routine?

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val timeInMillis = measureTimeMillis {
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Starting coroutine in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                val answer = doNetworkCall()
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Setting text in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                }
            }

        }
        Log.d(TAG, "(The operation took $timeInMillis ms)")

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Dispatcher is essentially a thread pool. When you use `launch(Dispatchers.Default)`, the Thread used to run the code in the coroutine will be obtained from `Dispatchers.Default`. Each time there is a suspend function call in the coroutine, when the coroutine resumes after that call, it might be resuming on a different Thread instance coming from the same `Dispatchers.Default` thread pool.

`"DefaultDispatcher-worker-1"` is the name of a literal `Thread` instance that came from the `Dispatcher.Default`'s pool.

`withContext` is itself a suspend function call, so any code after the `withContext` block will also be resumed on some thread from `Dispatchers.Default`. (There is none in your example).

The code inside `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` will be run on a thread from `Dispatchers.Main`.

`Dispatchers.Main` is a special Dispatcher that has only one thread, and that thread is the same Main Thread used by the OS.

You should rarely ever need to use `GlobalScope` and it is discouraged because it doesn't allow easy management of coroutine lifecycles. If you use `lifecycleScope` instead, your coroutines will be automatically cancelled when the associated Activity or Fragment is shut down. This is usually what you want, because an Activity or Fragment shouldn't be continuing to do work after it's gone.

Usually on Android, most coroutines should be launched from `lifecycleScope` or `viewModelScope` and should not need to have a Dispatcher specified since these scopes by default use `Dispatchers.Main` which is usually what you want. (Actually they use a different dispatcher called `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` which also uses the main thread but also can run the first part of a coroutine immediately without deferring to the next frame of the main thread loop. Not a distinction you need to worry about.) You can wrap the pieces of your coroutine that need other dispatchers in `withContext`. You don't need to do this if you are only calling suspend functions. By convention it is up to suspend functions to internally delegate to a specific Dispatcher if they need to.

An exception to the above paragraph might be if you're launching a coroutine in `viewModelScope` that does some blocking work and never touches anything that is main-thread-only. Then you can skip `withContext` and specify a dispatcher explicitly with `launch`.

Comment: Just a small detail but viewmodel and lifecycle scopes are actually backed by [`Dispatchers.Main.immediate`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-main-coroutine-dispatcher/immediate.html) as a means of extra optimization.

Comment: True, it's inaccurate to say they use Main, but that is a little confusing to a newcomer. I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Very, well explained. Can you please help me with any link that provides visualization for how coroutines behave with a thread pool?

Comment: I'm not aware of any diagram or article detailing how it works. I understand the basic concept of how a pool works and I haven't bothered to find out exactly what mechanism is used under the hood of coroutines.